# using duplicates values from one column to remove entire row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, drop-duplicates

I have the data in the .csv file uploaded in the following link

[Click here for the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OMm3T5WeCerhhBIkO4-isRPfOc97GnTO)

In this file, I have the following columns:

```
Team    Group    Model   SimStage  Points  GpWinner  GpRunnerup 3rd   4th
```

There will be duplicates in the columns **Team**. Another column is **SimStage**. Simstage has a series containing data from 0 to N (in this case 0 to 4)

I would like to keep row for each team at each Simstage value (i.e. the rest will be removed). when we remove, the duplicates row with lower value in the column **Points** will be removed for each Team and SimStage.
Since it is slightly difficult to explain using words alone, I attached a picture here.

[image: Sample pic that shows which rows to remove]

In this picture, the row with highlighted in red boxes will be be removed.

I used `df.duplicates()` but it does not work.

Comment: Hi @Dillion,
Thanks for the reply.
I am not removing first 3 rows. only teh row with  highlighted in red box will be removed. it is not necessary to be the first row. the columns **points** with lower value will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to only keep the highest value from the 'Points' column. Therefore, use the `first` aggregation function in pandas

Create the dataframe and call it `df`

```
data = {'Team': {0: 'Brazil',  1: 'Brazil',  2: 'Brazil',  3: 'Brazil',  4: 'Brazil',  5: 'Brazil',  6: 'Brazil',  7: 'Brazil',  8: 'Brazil',  9: 'Brazil'},
 'Group': {0: 'Group E',  1: 'Group E',  2: 'Group E',  3: 'Group E',  4: 'Group E',  5: 'Group E',  6: 'Group E',  7: 'Group E',  8: 'Group E',  9: 'Group E'},
 'Model': {0: 'ELO',  1: 'ELO',  2: 'ELO',  3: 'ELO',  4: 'ELO',  5: 'ELO',  6: 'ELO',  7: 'ELO',  8: 'ELO',  9: 'ELO'},
 'SimStage': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 4, 9: 4},
 'Points': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 1},
 'GpWinner': {0: 0.2,  1: 0.2,  2: 0.2,  3: 0.2,  4: 0.2,  5: 0.0,  6: 0.2,  7: 0.2,  8: 0.2,  9: 0.0},
 'GpRunnerup': {0: 0.0,  1: 0.0,  2: 0.0,  3: 0.0,  4: 0.0,  5: 0.2,  6: 0.0,  7: 0.0,  8: 0.0,  9: 0.2},
 '3rd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0},
 '4th': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# To be able to output the dataframe in your original order
columns_order = ['Team', 'Group', 'Model', 'SimStage', 'Points', 'GpWinner', 'GpRunnerup', '3rd', '4th']
```

## Method 1

```
# Sort the values by 'Points' descending and 'SimStage' ascending
df = df.sort_values('Points', ascending=False)
df = df.sort_values('SimStage')

# Group the columns by the necessary columns
df = df.groupby(['Team', 'SimStage'], as_index=False).agg('first')

# Output the dataframe in the orginal order
df[columns_order]

Out[]: 
     Team    Group Model  SimStage  Points  GpWinner  GpRunnerup  3rd  4th
0  Brazil  Group E   ELO         0       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
1  Brazil  Group E   ELO         1       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
2  Brazil  Group E   ELO         2       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
3  Brazil  Group E   ELO         3       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
4  Brazil  Group E   ELO         4       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
```

## Method 2

```
df.sort_values('Points', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Team', 'SimStage'])[columns_order]
Out[]: 
     Team    Group Model  SimStage  Points  GpWinner  GpRunnerup  3rd  4th
0  Brazil  Group E   ELO         0       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
2  Brazil  Group E   ELO         1       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
4  Brazil  Group E   ELO         2       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
7  Brazil  Group E   ELO         3       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
8  Brazil  Group E   ELO         4       4       0.2         0.0    0    0
```

Comment: Hi @Dillion, it removed the last 4 columns (GpWinner, GpRunnerUp, 3rd and 4th ) as well, I want to keep those columns too. How can i do that?
Thanks for the reply. I have been working out this for hours

Comment: The updated solution should work now. Note the change near the end to: `.agg('first')`

Comment: Thanks Dillion. I really appreciate your help. it saved me quite a few hours of time spending on it how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I am just creating a mini-dataset based on your dataset here with Team, SimStage and Points.

```
import pandas as pd

namesDf = pd.DataFrame() 
namesDf['Team'] = ['Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil']
namesDf['SimStage'] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
namesDf['Points'] = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1]
```

Now, for each Sim Stage, you want the highest Point value. So, I first group them by Team and Sim Stage and then Sort them by Points.

```
namesDf = namesDf.groupby(['Team', 'SimStage'], as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Points'], ascending = False)).reset_index(drop = True)
```

This will make my dataframe look like this, notice the change in Sim Stage with value 3:

```
     Team  SimStage  Points
0  Brazil         0       4
1  Brazil         0       4
2  Brazil         1       4
3  Brazil         1       4
4  Brazil         2       4
5  Brazil         2       1
6  Brazil         3       4
7  Brazil         3       2
8  Brazil         4       4
9  Brazil         4       1
```

And now I remove the duplicates by keeping the first instance of every team and sim stage.

```
namesDf = namesDf.drop_duplicates(subset=['Team', 'SimStage'], keep = 'first')
```

Final result:

```
     Team  SimStage  Points
0  Brazil         0       4
2  Brazil         1       4
4  Brazil         2       4
6  Brazil         3       4
8  Brazil         4       4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I really appreciate it.